# How can I remove these shelves without damaging the drywall?

Tags: drywall, repair, removal, shelving

It looks like these shelves are mounted onto the wall, but I don’t know how. There are no visible screws so I can’t figure out how to get the shelves off. I’m assuming they are hidden on the inside, but I just want to get them off the wall. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you posted your photo rotated by 90°? Can you fix it?

Comment: How about some close up pics of the brackets under one of the shelves. Also, maybe, the top of the shelf where it joins the wall, but after removing the tape.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's nailed to the wall with finish nails in the supports.  The shelves themselves are probably nailed to the supports with finish nails, and may have some nails that are angled into the sheetrock too.  I would bet that it's got some kind of caulking or adhesive in there as well.  I'd take a sharp knife and score around the entire thing, all the places where it meets the wall, then successively bigger tools to get in between the wall and the shelf.  Putty knife, small flat bar, and so on.  Put a piece of plywood or 1x between the tool and the wall for support to prevent crushing the sheetrock when prying.  At a minimum, you're going to have holes where the nails went through, and have to repair those.

Comment: Nailed, or, perhaps, screwed with plugs put over the screw holes (though, TBH, less likely, that's a lot of work for a little shelf like this). Look for any wood grain that suddenly goes a totally different direction - that'll be a plug over a screw.